# Only assignment, call, decrement can be used

Tags: c#

I'm trying to find integers in a certain range that are prime. I seem to be getting an error when I put a for loop in my else statement.

```
private static bool prime(int n,out int factor)
{
    factor = 1;

    if (n < 2)
        return false;
    else if (n == 2 || n == 3)
        return true;
    else if( n % 2 == 0) 
        return false;

    for(int r = 3; r < (Math.Sqrt(n) + 1); r + 2)
    {
        if ((Convert.ToInt32(n)) % r == 0)
            return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should fix your indentation so that your code makes some sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int r=3;r<(Math.Sqrt(n)+1);r+2)
```

`r+2` creates a result, but it isn't assigned to anything. You want either `r = r + 2` or `r += 2`

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of problems with your code.

Firstly you can fix the assigment problem like

r=r+2

secondly, your function needs to return something from all code paths. Which it isn't doing at the moment. I have returned true at the end, though you can choose your logic here.

```
private static bool prime(int n, out int factor)
    {

        factor = 1;
        if (n < 2)
            return false;
        else if (n == 2 || n == 3)
            return true;
        else if (n % 2 == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }


        for (int r = 3; r < (Math.Sqrt(n) + 1); r = r + 2)
        {


            if ((Convert.ToInt32(n)) % r == 0)
                return false;

        }

        return true;
    }
```